# Can I hide an image but not the div or class on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an in-line image in my responsive menu that I want to disappear when it goes into mobile mode.  I can't hide the class or the div that it is in as it will make the menu disappear as well.

```
<div id="h-nav">
<ul id="css3menu0 class="topmenu">
<li class="topmenu"><img src="images/menulead.jpg" name="menulead" id="menulead" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried adding this into my css, but it didn't work:

```
@media screen and (max-width:670px) {
.menulead img {display:none;}}
```

and also `#menulead img {display:none;}}`, as well as both ways without the 'img' but it didn't seem to work.  Is it possible to hide the image based on the image id?

If it helps to see what I mean, the website is [temporarily up here](http://traveltymerv.com/home).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
@media screen and (max-width:670px) {
.topmenu img {display:none;}
 }
```

or

```
@media screen and (max-width:670px) {
  #menulead {display:none;}
 }
```

P.S.: And *don't* assign the `.topmenu` class to both the `ul` and the `li`

P.P.S: You are missing a closing double-quote after `id="css3menu0`

Answer (score 0):

More simply you can add class to image as **class="hidden-xs"**, so that it will hide the image on xtra small devices.